# How do I get HDR+ working on Cyanogenmod for Nexus 5?

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera, nexus-5

HDR+ does not work on Cyanogenmod for Nexus 5. The Google Camera app simply crashes when selecting HDR+. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PA-GApps has [packaged the necessary support files](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=50684821), which are flashable as a zip. You can use [just the Google Camera module](http://d-h.st/users/TKruzze/?fld_id=37428#files).

> HDR support files from the Nexus 5 factory image have been added to
>   all GApps packages. This may help users who prefer to install Google
>   Camera from the Play Store [Stock/Full/Mini/Micro]

Comment: Both links are dead